How to prevent the FOR command stripping commas from filenames in a batch file? (Windows 11 command line)
When I pass a filename containing a comma to a batch file, and then attempt to process that filename using the FOR command, the FOR command removes the comma from the filename. Sample batch file:
echo %1
for /f "delims=`" %%i in ("%1") do echo "%%~fi"

If I pass a filename of Hartford, CT.txt to the above batch file, I would expect the output to be:
Hartford, CT.txt
Hartford, CT.txt

But the FOR command appears to remove the comma, and so the actual output of the batch file is:
Hartford, CT.txt
Hartford CT.txt

I am thinking it has something to do with delimiters, and I've read lots of articles & posts about this command - but have been unable to find a solution to this. If I remove the "delims=`" from the command, the comma is used to delimit the filename and the output is simply (and as expected):
Hartford

So even when a different delimiter is specified, it seems the command is swallowing the comma. is there any way to prevent this behavior?
EDIT: For @Compo I am adding a screenshot demonstrating the issue:


Question, why are you specifying that particular for /f delimiter? You need to show us exactly how you are passing the argument you are echoing as %1 to that part of the script. I have to ask because what you have shown as output seems impossible to me if it is an argument passed to the batch file itself. MyBatch.cmd Hartford, CT.txt would receive Hartford as %1, and as both commas and spaces are argument separators, CT.txt would be received as %2. If you had in fact used the recommended "Hartford, CT.txt" as the argument then you output would have shown those doublequotes.

...and you'd use "%~1" in your for loop, not "%1". Also, you should probably explain your example too. I see no benefit in using a for /f loop at all over a standard for loop. Even worse is that you appear only to be taking the long road to echoing %~f1. That of course would be pointless because the script couldn't magically know the full path to the string Hartford, CT.txt, even if it did exist.

It is pretty simple- I am passing in file names that may contain spaces and commas so i cannot use the default delimiters. A backtick is a pretty safe delimiter (meaning I don't use that character in my file naming conventions). If you add the code I supplied to a batch file and drag a file named "Hartford, CT.txt" onto the batch file, you'll see the problem in action. The same is true if I pass multiple filenames to the batch file. Ultimately I need to replace the extension on the file name, that is why I am using the FOR.

If you drag a file named Hartford, CT.txt onto your batch file, echo %1, your first line, does not output Hartford, CT.txt though, even though you are showing us that it does! If you cannot test these things before you post them, you have no basis for your question. It should output the doublequoted fully qualified absolute path of the dropped file. As for your reported issue, using "%~1", as I've said, fixes it. BTW, there are some characters which are disallowed in Windows file and directory names, so why not use one of those instead. My preference is ?, many others use |.

@Compo - please see the screenshot I added to my question- clearly I tested this before posting and included all the relevant code. Thanks for your input.

@Shoeless, I told you specifically what the output would show, and that your Hartford, CT.txt was impossible and untrue in the circumstances, I don't need proof of that. Your proof shows that what you told us was incorrect, and therefore backs up my statement. I also informed you twice to use "%~1", and that doing so fixes the issue. Please don't pick arguments with those who help you, and deliberately overlook that help in favor of someone else who is simply repeating it. There's no shame in being wrong, but trying to manifest that onto others is shameful.

The help output on running cmd /? in a command prompt window explains that a file name or folder name or any other argument string passed to a Windows command or an executable or script like a batch file containing a space or one of these characters &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ must be enclosed in ".
The file name C:\Temp\Hartford, CT.txt contains a comma and a space character.
The Windows Command Processor interprets following characters as argument string separators on not being inside a string with surrounding ":

The normal space character with code point value 32 (hexadecimal 0x20).
The comma character , with code point value 44 (hexadecimal 0x2C).
The semicolon character ; with code point value 59 (hexadecimal 0x3B).
The equal sign character = with code point value 61 (hexadecimal 0x3D).
The OEM encoded no-break space with code point value 255 (hexadecimal 0xFF).

One or more of these characters outside an argument string enclosed in " are interpreted like a single normal space, except there is before the caret character ^ with code point value 94 (hexadecimal 0x5E) which escapes the next character for being interpreted literally. Please note that ^ is only outside a double quoted argument string interpreted as escape character. The character ^ is interpreted literally inside a string beginning with " and ending with ".
The help output on running call /? in a command prompt window explains how argument strings like a file name passed to a batch file can be referenced inside the batch file.
COMMAND.COM supported only %1, %2, %3 … for referencing the first, second, third … argument string as passed to the batch file.
cmd.exe offers referencing the batch file arguments with usage of modifiers with enabled command extensions. The most often used modifier in batch files is just ~ like with %~1 to reference the first passed argument string with removal of the double quote character at the beginning and at the end of the argument string if the passed argument string has the character " at the beginning at all.
Note: If the argument string passed to a batch file does not begin with " but has a double quote character at the end, cmd.exe does not remove " from the end of the argument string on using %~1. That results usually very fast in a serious syntax error in a command line of the batch file reported by cmd.exe with an error message before processing of the batch file is exited next.
A file name like C:\Temp\Hartford, CT.txt must be passed to a batch file with:
"C:\Temp\Hartford, CT.txt"
The first argument string referenced with %1 without a modifier is therefore
"C:\Temp\Hartford, CT.txt" with the two double quotes.
The general solution in a batch file is referencing a passed file/folder name always with explicitly enclosing the string in double quotes and letting cmd.exe remove perhaps already existing surrounding double quotes from the argument string.
What is wrong on this command line?
for /f "delims=`" %%i in ("%1") do echo "%%~fi"

The parsing of this command line results in:
for /F "delims=`" %i in (""C:\Temp\Hartford CT.txt"") do echo "%~fi"


The lowercase FOR option /f becomes the uppercase option /F.
The loop variable reference %%i becomes %i.
%1 is replaced first by the first passed argument string "C:\Temp\Hartford, CT.txt" with the double quotes and next by "C:\Temp\Hartford CT.txt".
The loop variable reference with full name modifier %%~fi becomes %~fi.

What has happened with the comma?
There is inside the round brackets initially ""C:\Temp\Hartford, CT.txt"". The Windows Command Processor processes the command line from left to right. It encounters the first " and enables internally the parsing rule for a double quoted string. But the next character is once again " which disables internally the parsing rule for a double quoted string. The next characters are parsed therefore with interpreting the comma and the space as argument string separators. The two argument string separators are replaced for that reason by a single space as that is enough to separate the argument string ""C:\Temp\Hartford from the argument string CT.txt"".
The further processing by for /F and %%~fi is not as expected now.
The help output on running for /? describes for which purposes a for /F loop can be used:

Processing of lines read from a text file.
Processing a single string which can contain also multiple double quotes.
Processing the lines output to handle STDOUT (standard output) of a command line executed by one more cmd.exe started in background with %ComSpec% /c and the specified command line appended as arguments captured by cmd.exe processing the batch file with the for /F loop and processing these lines after the cmd.exe process started in background closed itself after finishing the command line execution.

A for /F loop is not needed at all in this case. A simple FOR loop is enough. Important is to let cmd.exe remove the surrounding " from the referenced argument string by using %~1 instead of %1 as the required surrounding " are part of the command line in the batch file.
for %%i in ("%~1") do echo %%~fi

Well, the same output can be achieved with just echo %~f1 as the fully qualified file/folder name modifier ~f can be used also on referencing the first argument string.

Aha! Thank you for clearly explaining what happened to the comma when processing the second line of my batch file.... And also for the clear and comprehensive response overall.
